# Changing the value of a variable in main to be available for other functions (c++)

Tags: c++

I declare this:

```
int xstartoftable;
void drawframe();

int main()
{
   int xstartoftable = 80-TLENGTH;
   drawframe();

   return 0
}
void drawframe();
{
   gotoXY(xstartoftable - 1, ystartoftable - 1);
}
```

The problem is that when I debug, the value of xstartoftable is random, not equal to the one in the main(). The code is over 150 lines, this is just the parts that are needed.

Comment: That's not real code. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Is this your actual code? It doesn't compile for me.

Comment: is `somevalue` a constant?  What is `y`?  At what point in the code are you looking at x?

Comment: Make sure you don't have `int x` anywhere in `main` or `i_use_x` first.

Comment: It would have been easier to answer your question if you had posted your actual code.  Copy-and-paste the code you fed to the compiler; don't re-type it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you redeclare your variable inside main.

```
int main()
{
   int xstartoftable = 80-TLENGTH; //extra declaration here
   drawframe();

   return 0;
}
```

Instead just do:

```
int main()
{
   xstartoftable = 80-TLENGTH; //leave out declaration
   drawframe();

   return 0;
}
```

This is similar to:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   {
      int x = 1;
   }
   printf("%d",x);
   //will print 0
}
```

On some compilers you might even get an error.

Answer (score 1):

`int xstartoftable = 80-TLENGTH;` declares a different `xstartoftable` that shadows the global one. g++ has a handy `-Wshadow` warning that catches this stuff.

You want the assignment `xstartoftable = 80-TLENGTH;` instead.